# Geocode rest api - filter for only latitude and longitude

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a restful URL to look up an address using google's geocoding service. It works but provides me more information that what i need. Is there a way to only return the latitude and longditude part of the json result.

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=300+Collins+St,+Docklands,+VIC&sensor=false&components=country:AU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, there's no other possibility. That's the standard return value. Try to use a filter in your program. You could split CSV file and cut off the needed part.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Geocoding Responses](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/):

> Note that the JSON response contains two root elements:
>
> - `"status"` contains metadata on the request. See [Status Codes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#StatusCodes) below.
> - `"results"` contains an array of geocoded address information and    geometry information.
>
> Generally, only one entry in the `"results"` array is returned for
>   address lookups,though the geocoder may return several results when
>   address queries are ambiguous.

The following example demonstrates how to extract location values from the returned JSON results:

```js
var requestUrl = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=300+Collins+St,+Docklands,+VIC&sensor=false&components=country:AU";
$.getJSON(requestUrl).done(function(data) {
    //extract locations 
    var locations = data.results.map(function(item){
       return item.geometry.location;
    });
    
    //print locations
    var output = JSON.stringify(locations, null, 2);
    $("#output").text(output);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre style="background-color: #c0c0c0" id="output"></pre>
```